# Automatically calculate years of experience from provided start/end dates

Tags: macros, programming, variable

[image]

I'm very very new to `LaTeX` and not even sure if this is possible.

```
        \resumeSubheading
            {Undergraduate Research Assistant}
            {6 Years \& 3 Months}  % 1 <----------------------------------------
            {College Station, TX}
            {}
            \resumeSubSubheading
                {Texas A\&M University}
                {June 2020 -- Present} % 2 <----------------------------------------
                \resumeItemListStart
                    \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}
                    \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data}
                    \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
                \resumeItemListEnd
            \resumeSubSubheading
                {Software Engineer I}
                {Oct 2014 - Sep 2016}  % 3 <----------------------------------------
                \resumeItemListStart
                    \resumeItem{Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines}
                \resumeItemListEnd
```

note: I'm a computer science student, so `Python` programming thinking and references ahead.

I want the lines 2 and 3 to be something like `\datediffprint{undergradResearchAssist}{June 2020}{\today}` and `\datediffprint{undergradResearchAssist}{Oct 2014}{Sep 2016}` respectively and it will store the values in a `Python` dictionary **like** way with `undergradResearchAssist` as key and the two dates as a list of difference of dates like like `[1182, 727,]` with 1128 being days diff between June 2020 to today and 727 being days diff between oct 2014 to sep 2016. Also the command `\datediffprint` would output the text shown in 2 and 3.

While 1 should be something like `\dateExperienceTime{undergradResearchAssist}` to print the experience in years and months as shown by calculating the sum of days in list `[1182, 727,]` and outputting.

The logic could be different, like instead of list of diffs just add the days to value. I want this so I won't have to manually calculate the experience for each job experience I have.

Comment: You might look at the tikz calendar and pgfplots dateplot libraries (Section 4.21.2).  While they are only concerned with displaying dates, they may have useful macros.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222354/calculations-with-dates

Comment: pgf calendar (as opposed to the tikz library) is useful. datenumber is also a possibility. Basically, you want to turn the date into a Julian date number for calculations. You could just do it in python, I assume, though you don't need to. Just don't try turning months/days into fractions of years. You want everything to be done on integers.