# Wrong date format if datenumber is loaded after datetime

Tags: packages, incompatibility, datetime

The date format is wrong when `datetime` and `datenumber` are used at the same time, `datenumber` being loaded after `datetime`.

As can be tested with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[english]{datenumber}
\begin{document}
\section{Package datenumber}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{21}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{22}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{23}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{31}
    \datedate
\end{itemize}

\section{Package datetime}
\begin{itemize}
\item \newdate{21}{21}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{21}
\item \newdate{22}{22}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{22}
\item \newdate{23}{23}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{23}
\item \newdate{31}{31}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{31}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

- when `datenumber` is not loaded, `datetime` displays the ordinal for 21, 22, 23 and 31 as 21<sup>st</sup>, 22<sup>nd</sup>, 23<sup>rd</sup> and 31<sup>st</sup>, as expected with UKenglish;
- when `datetime` is not loaded, `datenumber` displays the ordinal for 21, 22, 23 and 31 as 21st, 22nd, 23rd and 31st, as (almost) expected with UKenglish;
- when `datenumber` and `datetime` are loaded in this order, the error:

  ```
   ! You can't use `the character 2' after \advance.
   <argument> 2
               015
   l.9 \item \setdate{2015}{1}{21}
  ```

  already reported in [datetime and datenumber package conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/datetime-and-datenumber-package-conflict) arises;
- when datetime and datenumber are loaded in this order, the ordinal for 21, 22, 23 and 31 are displayed as:

  - 21st, 22nd, 23rd and 31st by datenumber, as (almost) expected with UKenglish;
  - 21<sup>th</sup>, 22<sup>th</sup>, 23<sup>th</sup> and 31<sup>th</sup> by datetime, and that's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both packages define a `\@modulo` macro. More precisely `datetime` requires package `fmtcount` and get it from there, while `datenumber` gives its own definition.

```
$ latexdef -p datetime @modulo

\@modulo:
macro:#1#2->\@DT@modctr =#1\relax \divide \@DT@modctr by #2\relax \multiply \@DT@modctr by #2\relax \advance #1 by -\@DT@modctr 

$ latexdef -p datenumber @modulo

\@modulo:
macro:#1#2->\@nom =#1\relax \@den =#2\relax \divide \@nom by \@den \multiply \@nom by \@den \@den =#1\advance \@den by -\@nom
```

This is presumably the source of the incompatibility.

Wrap the loading of `datenumber` as:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@modulo@SAVED\@modulo
\usepackage[english]{datenumber}
\let\DATENUMBER@modulo\@modulo
\def\setdaynamebynumber#1{%
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \ifnum\the@startyear=1800\advance \@tempcnta by 1\fi
  \ifnum\the@startyear=1900\advance \@tempcnta by 6\fi
  \ifnum\the@startyear=2000\advance \@tempcnta by 4\fi
  \DATENUMBER@modulo{\the\@tempcnta}{7}%
  \setcounter{datedayname}{\the\@den}%
  \addtocounter{datedayname}{1}%
  \setdayname{\thedatedayname}%
}
\def\ifleapyear#1{%#1 year
  \ifnum#1>1500
    \DATENUMBER@modulo{#1}{100}%
    \ifnum\@den=0
      \DATENUMBER@modulo{#1}{400}%
    \else
      \DATENUMBER@modulo{#1}{4}%
    \fi
  \else
    \DATENUMBER@modulo{#1}{4}%
  \fi
  \ifnum\@den=0
}
\let\@modulo\@modulo@SAVED
\makeatother
```

It then doesn't matter if you load it before or after `datetime`.

Answer (score 3):

Define own modulo functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{datenumber}
\makeatletter 
\let\dn@modulo\@modulo
\makeatother
\usepackage{datetime}
\makeatletter 
\let\dt@modulo\@modulo
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Package datenumber}
\makeatletter 
\let\@modulo\dn@modulo
\makeatother
\begin{itemize}
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{21}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{22}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{23}
    \datedate
  \item \setdate{2015}{1}{31}
    \datedate
\end{itemize}

\makeatletter 
\let\@modulo\dt@modulo
\makeatother
\section{Package datetime}
\begin{itemize}
\item \newdate{21}{21}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{21}
\item \newdate{22}{22}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{22}
\item \newdate{23}{23}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{23}
\item \newdate{31}{31}{1}{2015}
  \displaydate{31}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```